# How to sync ONLY some specific Picasa albums in Gallery app?

Tags: sync, gallery, picasa

I have plenty of Picasa albums and I really don't want all of them to be downloaded into my Android phone.

So my question is how can we select to sync only some selected albums only?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no such feature available. You can either enable the sync which will sync all your albums or to not to sync at all.